# Stroke gets cut (bug)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

so this new weird thing has started happening to me. I create a shape with a stroke, and randomly the stroke gets small cuts in it. If I move, scale, turn and change the shape the cuts disappear or change.

For example, in the image, the shapes are exactly the same, but one get two weird cuts and one just get one. If I change the stroke width the cuts disappear all together.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I'm making icons for a company and this is seriously messing up my work.

Cheers

[image: stroke getting cut]

Comment: The only time I've seen something similar to this is when a 3D effect is applied (extrude/bevel), but that does not appear to be the case here. If you [edit] your question to include a link to the .ai file (via Dropbox or similar), I'd be happy to take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just an error in the view. Try switching to CPU-Preview in the View Panel instead of GPU-Preview.